# WPF control is on top of the window border, how do I stop that?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, animation, wpf-controls, window

I have a WPF window and an Image in a grid in the window. I am animating the Image so it moves from out of view (beyond widow location) into the window.

The animation is nice and smooth and everything works but I notice the image is over top of the window border while it is moving. The image at the end of this question is what it looks like.

Why would the image be over top of the window border, and how do I get it to be "under" the border?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried ClipToBounds="True" on the image? You could also try a clipmask. But i might not fully understand your question. Because i don't understand the image :)

Comment: Found the answer by trial and error, but thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of trial and error it seems the problem was the fact I was moving the image in a grid that had no defined width, so the width would expand over the border when moving the image thus extending the "client" area of the window and showing over the window area.

Once I defined a specific width of the grid, everything worked.